# how to make a similar [mat-dialog-close] in a div?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have one *ngFor in a card, and i need to after click in the card, get the selected data in my component.

I try:

```
<div (click)="setProdutoEscolhido(data.produtos[i])" *ngFor="let produto of data.produtos; let i = index" class="card col-md-6">
   <div class="view overlay">
      <img *ngIf="produto.foto_prin_1 !=  null" class="card-img-top" src="{{produto.foto_prin_1}}"
       alt="Card image cap">
       <a href="#!">
          <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
       </a>
</div>
```

My typescript:

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalProcuraProdutoVinculacao>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
}

setProdutoEscolhido(produto:Produtos){
  this.data.produtos = produto;
  this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

In my component parent i put in my callback function:

```
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.produtoAlvo = result;
    console.log(this.produtoAlvo);
  });
```

If i try this way, i receive:

> ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and
>   iterables are allowed

If i try to use [mat-dialog-close] in my div, i receive:

> "[mat-dialog-close]" it's not a know property of div.

If i change the div to a button [mat-dialog-close]="data.produtos[i]" i can get the data, but the css spoils.

There's one way to get a similar [mat-dialog-close] in my div?

I'm using this dialog:

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api

@Edit: i change my code to:

```
 <div *ngFor="let produto of data.produtos; let i = index" class="card col-md-6" (click)="setProdutoEscolhido(produto)">
```

ts:

```
setProdutoEscolhido(produto: any){
  this.data = produto;
  this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

but now i have undefined in my console.log:

```
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.produtoAlvo = result;
    console.log(this.produtoAlvo);
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MatDialogClose` directive can only be used with `button` elements, but its input option (e.g. `[mat-dialog-close]="result"`) can be accomplished through `DialogRef` using the `dialogResult` parameter of the `close()` function:

```
setProdutoEscolhido(produto: any){
    this.data = produto;
    this.dialogRef.close(produto);
}
```